# Using React contextTypes with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I know it's rather undocumented feature, but since the `react-router` has no clean way of passing props to child route components, I wanted to use context.

```
<Router history={history}>
    <Route component={Application} path="/(:id)">
        <IndexRoute component={EditDocument} />
    </Route>
</Router>

class Application extends Component {

    static childContextTypes = {
        charts: PT.array.isRequired,
    }

    getChildContext() {
        return { charts: this.getCharts() };
    }

    render() {
        return <div>{this.props.children}</div>
    }
}

class EditDocument extends Component {

    static contextTypes = {
        charts: PT.array.isRequired,
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.context.charts === undefined
    }
}
```

I am using React 0.13 for now. Can this be solved using 0.14?

Comment: It might be worth to look at those issues [react-router#1857](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1857#issuecomment-139228924) and [react-router#1531](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1531)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {someExtraProp: something })}

So you pass additional stuff to your views

e.g.

```
function renderApp(data) {

var React = require('react');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;

var App = React.createClass({

render: function () {

  return (

<AppShell>

        {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {data:data})}

    </AppShell>
  );
}
});

var rootRoute = {
component: 'div',
childRoutes: [{
path: '/',
component: {App},
///etc
}]
};

React.render(
```

React.render(

```
 <Router routes={rootRoute}/>,
document.body
```

);

```
,
document.body
);

}
renderApp(data);
```

Hope that.s useful, let me know if I need to explain it better

Comment: Yeah, I found out about cloneElement somewhere else. It works the best. I just don't feel it's a "clean" solution.

Answer (score 1):

To pass props to your component you override the `createElement` method of `Router` before you create the `Router`:

```
const createElement = function(Component, props) {
   return <Component {...props} myProps={{your: 'props'}} />;
 };

<Router history={history} createElement={createElement}>
    <Route component={Application} path="/(:id)">
        <IndexRoute component={EditDocument} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

This method worked for us. The same can be done on the server with `RoutingContext`.

Comment: Same answer as @knowbody, so the same response. I don't have access to the requested props when creating Router. They are basically created in the Application component. Using `createElement` I cannot access these.

Comment: Okay, now I understand what you mean. The weird thing is that our app is set up exactly as your code and it works. What differs is that we use our own createElement and we use react 0.14-rc1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use React Router [`createElement`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#createelementcomponent-props)

> You can easily set it up to selectively pass props from router state or your app state to route components (based on route config if you want to).

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that, but I am still missing point how to use that. You cannot access parent props in that function.